# Inconsistent object comparison behaviour when inheriting from dict

Tags: python, comparison-operators

This problem arose from a failing test that refused to fail locally, and would only fail on our CI server.

It turned out some rather dodgy object comparison was being unintentionally done.

I'm now rather curious as to why the behavior is so different between two installations of the same Python version (2.7.9).

This test case could probably be simplified further, but this is what I've got:

```
import operator


class Thing(dict):
    def __int__(self, number):
        return self['number']

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self['number'] > other

thing = Thing({'number': 2})

for o in [
        operator.lt,
        operator.le,
        operator.eq,
        operator.ne,
        operator.ge,
        operator.gt]:
    print o
    print o(0.01, thing)
    print o(thing, 0.01)
```

And the result of running it locally is:

```
<built-in function lt>
True
False
<built-in function le>
True
False
<built-in function eq>
False
False
<built-in function ne>
True
True
<built-in function ge>
False
True
<built-in function gt>
False
True
```

But on the Travis CI server it is:

```
<built-in function lt>
True
True
<built-in function le>
False
True
<built-in function eq>
False
False
<built-in function ne>
True
True
<built-in function ge>
True
False
<built-in function gt>
True
True
```

What kind of comparison behavior is Python falling back to, and why would it exhibit such different behavior on two installations of the same version?

My initial thought was some kind of `id` based comparison, but from looking at the value of the `id`, they don't correlate at all with the results of the comparisons.

### Update:

This differing behavior only happens when the class inherits from `dict`. When it inherits from `object`, the comparisons behave the same on both installations, and give the same results as the local result above.

### Update 2:

I've just found that I can simplify the test case even further with just the `__int__` and the `__gt__` methods, but if I remove either of those methods then the strange behavior disappears.

Comment: An interesting question!  Can you reproduce the behavior if you use a class that just inherits from `object` and not `dict`?  I haven't yet figured out what is going on, but one thing to be aware of is that `dict` defines some comparison operations that your class doesn't (in fact it defines all of the ordinary inequality comparisons).

Comment: Trying this at my machine le, ne and ge do not call the functions defined in the class. This seems interesting to me because the answers on your server and local machine differ, but as far as I understand if only builtins are used differing answers are.. very strange?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing just now, and found that this behavior only happens when it inherits from `dict`. I've simplified the test case above. When inheriting from `object` they it behaves the same on both installations.

Comment: `functools.total_ordering` --> "Class decorator that fills in missing ordering methods"... but the ordering methods are not missing from `dict`.

Comment: @tdelaney, that's a great point! But what could explain the difference in behavior between the two installations?

Comment: And I've just found that I can simplify the test case even further with just the `__int__` and the `__gt__` methods, but if I remove either of those methods then the strange behavior disappears.

Comment: @Acorn - not sure. My guess is that things like `dict.__lt__` may depend on how the unordered dict was constructed and could vary by who-knows-what. I'm trying to figure out what `__lt__` even means on a dict!

Comment: The thing is, though, `total_ordering` on a `dict` inheritor isn't going to work anyway because operators such as `__lt__` that already exist on `dict` don't get overwritten to the fancy comparator.

Comment: @Acorn, what you are testing is whether 0.01 is greater than a `dict` which is a nonsensical operation.

Comment: Yep, it's totally bonkers, but I'm still curious to know what it's doing, and why the behavior might be inconsistent! :)

Comment: Could you try out `__int__(self)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation, and based on @BrenBarn's fantastic answer I've found the root of the strange behaviour.

The last resort step of the "undefined" comparison is to compare the memory location of the object *types*. After comparing `id(type(thing))` and `id(type(0.02))` locally and on the CI server, I see that `Thing`'s id is always higher locally, and always lower on the CI server!

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in comments, `dict` already defines all the comparison operators.  The [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) behavior is:

> Objects of different types, except different numeric types and different string types, never compare equal; such objects are ordered consistently but arbitrarily

In other words, dicts are specifically defined to *allow* comparisons with other types, but for the result of such comparisons to be undefined.  (This was changed in Python 3 so that these sorts of inter-type comparisons are no longer allowed.)

When you override just some of the comparison operators for your type, you complicate things even more.  Since your type defines `__gt__` but not `__lt__`, `thing > 0.01` will use your custom `__gt__`, but `thing < 0.01` will use the default (undefined) comparison behavior.  So you get a type that sometimes uses a deterministic rule, and sometimes gives undefined behavior, depending on which comparison operators you use.  I don't know why you see the precise pattern of results you're seeing, but the bottom line is that your class relies on undefined behavior, so you can't expect any consistency in comparisons using this type.  The two implementations of Python could be doing something differently at some arcane implementation level that produces different undefined behavior.  The point of undefined behavior is you aren't supposed to know how it works (or you might start relying on it).

Incidentally, `total_ordering` here is a no-op, and the behavior should be the same if you remove it.  `total_ordering` only adds comparison operators that aren't already defined, but `dict` already defines all of them, so `total_ordering` won't do anything.  If you want to make your own ordering relation on a subclass of a type that already defines its own comparison behavior (like dict), then you need to manually override every individual comparison operator.

Comment: One bit of behavior I'm struggling to understand is the fact that when I remove the `__int__` method from the class, it ceases to exhibit this behavior, but the `__int__` method is never called when the comparisons are made..

Comment: Ah, does `PyNumber_Check` return `True` if the object has an `__int__` method? And if they both pass the `PyNumber_Check` then it falls back to the last resort comparison which is memory pointers?

Comment: @Acorn: That sounds plausible.  I agree that is surprising, but it's still valid undefined behavior :-).

Comment: Yep, after further investigation, the last resort comparison is to compare the memory location of the object types. After comparing `id(type(thing))` and `id(type(0.02))` locally and on the CI server, I see that `Thing`'s `id` is always higher locally, but always lower on the CI server! Mystery solved :)